# How turn off microphone in windows c++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I wand make code for turn off my microphone ( it make whitenoise), how i can do it by vc++ (not .NET)?

Comment: Why don't you just disable it with the device manager?

Comment: Or disable microphone echo in Sounds & Audio Devices?

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: I need some WinAPI! I can quickly disable it use "Win + r" from my keyboard. I don't have mouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below snippet, it should work for you...

```
void setVolume(DWORD volume) {
HMIXER mixer;

if (mixerOpen(&mixer, 0, 0, 0, 0) != MMSYSERR_NOERROR) {
    MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Error: mixerOpen()", NULL, MB_ICONHAND);
    return;
}

// Get the line info
MIXERCAPS mixcaps;
MIXERLINE mixerLine;
mixerGetDevCaps(0, &mixcaps, sizeof(MIXERCAPS));
mixerLine.cbStruct = sizeof(MIXERLINE);
mixerLine.dwComponentType = MIXERLINE_COMPONENTTYPE_DST_WAVEIN;
mixerLine.dwSource = 0;
mixerLine.dwDestination = 0;

if (mixerGetLineInfo(reinterpret_cast<HMIXEROBJ>(mixer), &mixerLine, MIXER_GETLINEINFOF_SOURCE)
    != MMSYSERR_NOERROR) {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Error: mixerGetLineInfo()", NULL, MB_ICONHAND);
        return;
}

// Get control for mixerline
MIXERCONTROL mixerCtrl;
MIXERLINECONTROLS mixerLineCtrl;

mixerLineCtrl.cbStruct = sizeof(MIXERLINECONTROLS);
mixerLineCtrl.dwLineID = mixerLine.dwLineID;
mixerLineCtrl.dwControlType = MIXERCONTROL_CONTROLTYPE_VOLUME;
mixerLineCtrl.cControls = 1;
mixerLineCtrl.pamxctrl = &mixerCtrl;
mixerLineCtrl.cbmxctrl = sizeof(MIXERCONTROL);
mixerLineCtrl.cControls = 5;

if (mixerGetLineControls(reinterpret_cast<HMIXEROBJ>(mixer), &mixerLineCtrl, MIXER_GETLINECONTROLSF_ONEBYTYPE)
    != MMSYSERR_NOERROR) {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Error: mixerGetLineControls()", NULL, MB_ICONHAND);
        return;
}

// Volume..
MIXERCONTROLDETAILS mixerCtrlDetails;
MIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED mixerCtrlDetailsUnsigned;

mixerCtrlDetailsUnsigned.dwValue = volume;
mixerCtrlDetails.dwControlID = mixerCtrl.dwControlID;
mixerCtrlDetails.cbStruct = sizeof(MIXERCONTROLDETAILS);
mixerCtrlDetails.cMultipleItems = 0;
mixerCtrlDetails.paDetails = &mixerCtrlDetailsUnsigned;
mixerCtrlDetails.cbDetails = sizeof(MIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED);
mixerCtrlDetails.cChannels = 1;

if (mixerSetControlDetails(reinterpret_cast<HMIXEROBJ>(mixer), &mixerCtrlDetails, MIXER_OBJECTF_HMIXER | MIXER_GETCONTROLDETAILSF_VALUE)
    != MMSYSERR_NOERROR) {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Error: mixerSetControlDetails()", NULL, MB_ICONHAND);
        return;
}

mixerClose(mixer);
}
```

In vista and 7 there is change in API have a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2007/03/06/how-do-i-change-the-master-volume-in-windows-vista.aspx